# Cannot convert string to Guid

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I want to get selection made in a dropdown and store it.

How can I fix this error for when setting value from dropdown `dropmarket`?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Guid'

```
cellsite.Market.MarketID = dropmarket.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to

```
cellsite.Market.MarketID = Guid.Parse(dropmarket.SelectedValue);
```

A `string` is not implicitly convertible to a `Guid`. You use the [`Guid.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.parse.aspx) method to convert a string to a `Guid`.